High current voltage controlled current source MOSFET selection
I am working on adjustable voltage controlled current source (2 to 3 A) for my project.
I tried different NMOS for the projects, but they all burned.
In my application, the resistance of my load is very low, like 0.5 ohm to 1 ohm.
I want to control the current on the load from 2 to 3 A (maximum 5 A also fine) using the DAC function of a microcontroller. In my opinion, MOSFET is burns due to limitations in Pds.


You suspect power limit issues. What does the datasheet say the expected power dissipation limit is? (What is the datasheet?) Does your layout match the test setup used for the power rating?

R1 resistor is also a "big" too high ... 100 ohm should be ok.

Consider using a MOSFET driver with built-in overcurrent protection. Also, is it some manner of inductive load like a solenoid? In that case reverse EMF might as well be the culprit.

In datasheet, at Vds 5V, Ids can be 4A in dc. And actually, through datasheet I dont see any wrong.


In my opinion, my mosfet is burnt due to limitation in Pds.

You are probably right.
With a 0.5 ohm load and 3 A output, the output FET is consuming
$$3.5\ {\rm V}\times 3\ {\rm A}=10.5\ {\rm W}$$
Even if your FET is designed for this kind of power consumption it will only work with an adequate heat sink. In the case of SMT FET's, that heatsink will be provided by the copper of the circuit board it is mounted to.
Your options include:

Design your board to provide adequate heat sinking

Choose a FET in a package like TO-220 that can fit an air-fin heat sink.

Redesign your circuit entirely to use a switching design that doesn't require using a transistor that consumes much more power than the actual load.



What about the 5A and 0.5 Ohm ?

@D.A.S., 12.5 W. Doesn't change the general gist of the answer: OP needs to do something different.

OK but this ignores the variable current to a load which shares 50% power at half load,

@D.A.S., no, it doesn't. At 5 A, 0.5 ohms, the load drops 2.5 V. That leaves 2.5 V across the control FET. 2.5 V x 5 A is exactly how I calculated the 12.5 W. The load would also be consuming 12.5 W, which means 50% of the total power provided by the 5 V supply goes to the load and 50% to the FET, just as you said.

OK I agree  but I read  " 2 to 3 A (maximum 5 A""  as 2~5A @ 0.5ohm ,so I am just commenting on your assumptions not the results.

In my case, I am not available to put heat sink. Therefore, is is possible to change MOSFET to higher Pds model?

My op-amp can receive mostly 15V. I am thinking of replacing the MOSFET to bigger package ones.

@djdlgl, the 15 V supply to the op-amp has nothing to do with the power consumed by the MOSFET. Is the voltage at the net labelled "+5V" or is it higher? About changing MOSFETs, the one that is designed for higher Pds will probably also require a big heatsink --- read the datasheet to understand what heatsink was used to set the Pds spec.

You are operating a part designed to be used as a switch, as a linear pass element.  The surface-mount package can dissipate very little heat.  The datasheet is very clear about the thermal limitations of this component.
With R3 = 0.5 ohm and 3 A, the FET package is trying to dissipate 10.5 W.  At that power level, even a TO-220 part would burn up without a heatsink.  Note that the FET would be preforming as a 1.167 ohm resistor, nowhere near its rated Rdson.  In this type of application, the Rdson spec rarely applies.
Choose a FET designed for this power level and add an appropriate heatsink.

You need an active cooler sink & fan, the size of a CPU heatsink (est.) from an old PC tower.
Active Load Design Specs

I = 5A max
R = 0.5 min
P = I^2*R = 12.5W  load
Load = V(R)=IR=2.5V
Vdd= 5V
FET Vds also = 2.5V = Vdd-V(R) must deliver 5A*5V=25W
Case Temp rise = 25’C max.(pref.)
Load thermal Rth = 2 ‘C/W = 25/12.5 ‘C/W
.

Notes
If dummy load R is a 25W 0.5 Ohm resistor with sink mount flange then both FET and fixed R load can share heatsink with a rating of 1’C/W which is like a standard modern tower CPU heatsink & fan 5V with silver oxide heat grease & FET drain TO-220 insulator.
This way the desired 25W max. power is shared by 2 parts to increase surface area to the sink.
To compute final thermal resistance, and temp rise, the equivalent R network adds all series and parallel parts to the shared heating Rca (case to ambient).
Added
Also if you want 5A always choose a 50 mV max drop or less.
Even if you use a 2W resistor in this case for R3 that is excessive.
R3 temp rise
I^2R = 450 mW for 3A and 1.25W for 5A. To estimate R temp rise using Pd/Max *125’C. So for a 2W part dumping only 1.25W heat rises 80’C which will sizzle water.

Yes, sure. It will be great if I could add heat sink like ordinary electronics. However, due to size limitation, it is not possible... Thererfore, I am finding a better MOSFET that can manage 2A to 3A.

This is a thermodynamics , power resistance per degree 'C problem, not a linear RdsOn choice. Sorry, that won't work for linear loads, only PWM nonlinear load types.

..unless you intended to switch fixed resistors rated at high power
